# Why my code won't work on iphone 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, call

So i make an application that calls an number:

```
NSString *cleanedString = [[number componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-+()"] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSString *escapedPhoneNumber = [cleanedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", escapedPhoneNumber]];
UIWebView *mCallWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init]  ;
[self.view addSubview:mCallWebview];
[mCallWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];
```

However a tester with iPhone 5 reported that it's not working on his phone while on main works fine. He doesn't get any crashes or anything.

Thank u!

Comment: Have you tried running your code in iPhone5 simulator? iphone simulator -> Hardware -> device -> iphone (Retina 4 - inch)

Comment: Yes i/m running in iphoe 5 simulator all time but it works no problem. (it just doesn't make calls)

Answer (score 2):

```
  NSString *number = YOUR-NUMBER;       
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@",number]];

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Try with this code, it will navigate back to your app after finished call

Comment: beware that the `telprompt:` schema is not official and can therefore be removed by Apple without any notice.

Answer (score 1):

The `tel:` URL schema is used incorrectly in your code, remove the `//`

```
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", escapedPhoneNumber]];
```

Comment: is that surly the reason, that tester is kinda important so i don't want to report false solutions, also why does it work on another iPhone, because it/s older?

Comment: Well I not totally sure, but have noticed that the `tel://` will not work on every device. If you want to be 100% sure that you can solve the problem get a iPhone 5 to test it on the device in debug mode and check what is going on.

Comment: you can view a list of iPhone URL Schemes here: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Phone

Answer (score 0):

you can check this code.i hope this will help you.

```
NSString *phoneNo = @"your phone no";
NSString *strAppend  = [@"tel:" stringByAppendingString:phoneNo];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
  openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strAppend]];
```